# User Control embedded on a page changes ClientID of controls

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls, clientid

I have a user control(.ascx), which I am embedding in my page(.aspx), as below:

```
<%@ Register TagName="UI" TagPrefix="my" Src="~/userControls/UI.ascx" %> 
<my:UI runat="server" ID="mytestui" />
```

When page is loaded the controls(textboxes, dropdowns etc), inside the user control, changes automatically. Say I have a textbox called txtTest it changes to  mytestui_txtTest.

As you can see it takes the ID of user control above and appends it to control.

Is there any way to prevent this from happening?

Comment: May I ask why, and what you are trying to achieve with the ClientIDs?

Comment: What ID are you passing and what how is the control you are looking for defined?

Comment: passing the ID from usercontrol

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happens because your control is a subclass of `UserControl` class, which implements `INamingContainer` interface. By default all controls that implement this interface prepend children's IDs with their own IDs, thus insuring that every ID on the page is unique.

To aviod this behavior you have two options:

1. Create server control, inheriting not from `UserControl` but from `Control` class directly. This one does not implement `INamingContainer`. However you won't have markup file, and have to generate all controls programmatically.
2. **[Edit: ASP.NET 4 only]** Use `ClientIDMode="Static"` for child controls. This mode insures that server and client IDs of the control are exactly the same. In this case this is a job of a developer to make sure that this control is used only once on the page to avoid ID duplicates.

Comment: Thanks for the answer I cannot go for first option, as I need markup. For second option I tried ClientIDMode first of all it is not in properties and nothing changes when I add it to asp:dropdown

Comment: Which version of ASP.NET are you using? Modes for ClientID were introduce only in 4th.

Comment: @Sam, then I am afraid there is no options other then first one. Lengthy IDs were a big pain of ASP.NET up to 4th version. But maybe you can still live with those? What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Basically am doing a clean up and moving the UI to user control, but the user control is inheriting from other partial classes where one of these classes is inherited from usercontrol. in one of them I am looking for an id by name as such Control control = ValidationBase.FindControlRecursive(Page.Master ?? (Control)Page, id); and this is throwing the error...

Comment: @Sam, what is the error? Btw I think you should update the post with that info

Answer (score 2):

What version of .Net are you using? If >= 4.0 you can use `ClientIDMode="Static"` as Andrei said. You can set it at control or page level as well.

Comment: Why do you need the original ID of your controls? Are you trying to retrieve them from client-side?

Comment: please see the comment on Andrei's anser

Comment: I didnt get that, can you explain please

Comment: Sorry, that was winforms way... anyway, you can compare control's UniqueID property as well instead of only comparing ID, maybe that will work...

Answer (score 1):

If you want to access controls from client side use the class accessor of jQuery  instead of using direct ID's (Ensure that this class is uniquely assigned to your control or you will get an array of controls.

```
$('.ClassName').val();
```